# Show that if $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable and $J_f(v_0)\not=0$, then $v_0$ is not a local extremum of $f$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function and suppose that for some $v_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$, the Jacobian matrix $J_f(v_0)\not=0$. Prove that $v_0$ is not a local maximum.

Now I know this is the contrapositive of the theorem that if $J_f(v_0)=0$ then $v_0$ is a critical point. But I wanted prove this without the contrapositive by showing there exists points $v_1,v_2\in\mathbb{R^n}$ in every neighborhood of $v_0$ such that $\;f(v_1)\leq f(v_0)\leq f(v_2)$.

Can I get help with this?

EDIT: (unrelated to proving the proposition without contrapositive) I was given a hint that there exists some $w$ such that $J_f(v_0)\cdot w\not=0$ and that I should study the function $g(t)=f(v_0+tw)$.

Comment: Consider a vector $\vec{v}$ such that $J_f(v_0)\vec{v}>0$ (this is possible because the Jacobian does not vanish).  Consider the direction $v_0+t\vec{v}$, this is now a univariate function.  Now, use Taylor's theorem on the univariate problem (perhaps the second order version of Taylor's theorem) and choose $t$ small enough so that the first order term dominates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Saying $J_f(v_0)\ne 0$ is equivalent to saying $\nabla f (v_0) \ne 0,$ which is equivalent to saying some $\partial f/\partial x_k (v_0)\ne 0.$ Now you're back in one variable, where the conclusion is easy.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so what's $g'(0)$? It's

\begin{align}
g'(0) &=\left. Jf(v_0 + wt)\right|_{t=0} \cdot w \\
&= Jf(v_0) \cdot w > 0.
\end{align}
That means that for some small $b > 0 $, you have $-b < 0 < b$ and $g(-b) < g(0) < g(b)$, by a straightforward epsilon-delta argument.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\vec{v}$ be a vector such that $J_f(v_0)\vec{v}>0$; in your case, this is just the dot product $\nabla f(v_0)\cdot \vec{v}$.

Now, consider $f(v_0+t\vec{v})$ as a function of $t$.  Call this function $g(t)=f(v_0+t\vec{v})$.  By [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem),
$$
g(t)=g(0)+g'(0)t+h(t)t
$$
where $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}h(t)=0$.  Taylor's theorem does *not* require that $f$ has many derivatives; in fact, it only requires that $f$ is differentiable once.  (This is a difference between Taylor's theorem and Taylor series).

Since $g'(0)=\nabla f(v_0)\cdot \vec{v}\not=0$, we can choose $t$ sufficiently close to $0$ and positive so that $|h(t)|<\frac{1}{2}(\nabla f(v_0)\cdot \vec{v}).$

Then 
\begin{align*}
g(t)-g(0)&=((\nabla f(v_0)\cdot \vec{v})+h(t))t\\
&>((\nabla f(v_0)\cdot \vec{v})-\frac{1}{2}(\nabla f(v_0)\cdot \vec{v}))t\\
&=\frac{1}{2}(\nabla f(v_0)\cdot \vec{v})t>0.
\end{align*}
Therefore, $g(t)>g(0)$.

Comment: we can't use Taylor series here because we are only told that $f$ is differentiable once (not even continuously differentiable)

Comment: You can use the first order part of Taylor's theorem.  It doesn't require that the function is infinitely differentiable.